# Adding square matrices in O(n) time?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, complexity-theory

Say we have two square matrices of the same size `n`, named `A` and `B`.

`A` and `B` share the property that each entry in their main diagonal diagonals is the same value (i.e., `A[0,0] = A[1,1] = A[2,2] ... = A[n,n]` and `B[0,0] = B[1,1] = B[2,2] ... = B[n,n]`).

Is there a way to represent `A` and `B` so that they can be added to each other in O(n) time, rather than O(n^2)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In general: No.**

For an `n`x`n` matrix, there are `n^2` output values to populate; that takes `O(n^2)` time.

**In your case: No.**

Even if `O(n)` of the input/output values are dependent, that leaves `O(n^2)` that are independent.  So there is no representation that can reduce the overall runtime below `O(n^2)`.

**But...**

In order to reduce the runtime, it is necessary (but not necessarily sufficient) to increase the number of dependent values to `O(n^2)`.  Obviously, whether or not this is possible is dictated by the particular scenario...

Comment: Also, there are `O(n^2)` independent values to calculate, so it takes `O(n^2)` time for _any_ representation.

Comment: I wouldn't say /any/ though ;) If the matrices are sparse, then you can get away with `O(nnz)` with `nnz` the number of non-zeros, where, often, `nnz=O(n)`. In particular, if his matrix *is* diagonal, then you directly have an `O(n)` solution.

Comment: @WhitAngl: In both of those cases, O(n^2) of the values are identical, so it doesn't contradict what my answer says ;)

Comment: it contradicts the "it takes `O(n^2)` time" to do it : if you just store the diagonal, then it really takes `O(n)` time :)

Comment: @WhitAngl: "*Even if O(n) of the input/output values are dependent...*"; that's not the case in either of your scenarios.

Comment: yep, I saw that : and in this case, there *is* a representation that can reduce the overall runtime below `O(n^2)` : that's the diagonal representation (for instance ; or band or CRS/CCS...). Otherwise, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @WhitAngl: It's ok, I don't disagree that there are potentially O(n) techniques for sparse/diagonal matrices.  But as those cases have more than O(n) dependent values, they aren't relevant to my answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

To complement Oli Cherlesworth answer, I'd like to point out that in **the specific case of sparse matrices**, you can often obtain a runtime of `O(n)`.

For instance, if you happen to *know* that your matrices are diagonal, you also *know* that the resulting matrix will be diagonal, and hence you only need to compute `n` values.
Similarly, there are band matrices that can be added in `O(n)`, as well as more "random" sparse matrices. In general, in a sparse matrix, the number of non-zero elements per row is more or less constant (you obtain these elements from a finite element computation for example, or from graph adjacency matrices etc.), and as such, using an appropriate representation such as "[Compressed row storage](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_Row_Storage)" or "Compressed column storage", you will end up using `O(n)` operations to add your two matrices.

Also a special mention for sublinear randomized algorithms, that only propose you to know the final value that is "not-too-far" from the real solution, up to random errors.